# Rails: Query to get collection associated with collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, has-many-through

So I have these four classes:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :water_rights
end

class WaterRight < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :place_of_use_area_water_rights
  has_many :place_of_use_areas, through: :place_of_use_area_water_rights
end

class PlaceOfUseAreaWaterRight < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :place_of_use_area
  belongs_to :water_right
end

class PlaceOfUseArea < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :place_of_use_area_water_rights
  has_many :water_rights, through: :place_of_use_area_water_rights
end
```

and I call `User.first.water_rights` and get a collection of WaterRights. My question is how do I get a collection of PlaceOfUseAreas associated with those WaterRights without doing something like this:

```
areas = []
water_rights.each do |wr|
  areas << wr.place_of_use_areas
end
areas.flatten.uniq{ |a| a.id }
```

This works but it makes a new query for every single WaterRight. I'm looking for a way to make one query to get the collection of associated PlaceOfUseAreas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just want to get all associated `PlaceOfUseAreas` objects in single query, right?

If so, Rails have pretty single line solution for it:

```
PlaceOfUseArea.joins(:water_wights).uniq
```

Read more [about joins method](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/joins) if you want more information.

Comment: Yes but I would like to get PlaceOfUseAreas only for a certain User's water rights. `PlaceOfUseArea.joins(:water_rights).where(water_rights: { user_id: User.first.id }).uniq` I'm guessing something like that would work? Also, is there any way to use `uniq` on just the ID column? I have a JSON column that seems to be throwing this error: `PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  could not identify an equality operator for type json`.

Comment: I ended up using this query: `PlaceOfUseArea.joins(:water_rights).where(water_rights: { user_id: user.id }).group('place_of_use_areas.id')` and it got me what I needed. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: You're welcome! And one more tip about uniq: you can use `&block` for it. For example: `PlaceOfUseArea.joins(:water_wights).uniq{|result| result.id}`. You can read more in [official documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Array.html#method-i-uniq)

Comment: Ah, that's perfect! I kept ending up at the [query methods docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/uniq). I didn't even think about the fact that I would be using the array method. Thanks again!